# Maximum number of rows supported by SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We are in need to process 100 million rows with size 20 -25 GB.

We have planned to use SQL Server Management Studio for processing, but don't know the capacity of SQL Server Management Studio. What is the maximum number of rows supported by SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server   You should have no worries

Comment: "process rows" has no meaning. SSMS is just an application that is used to manage and query sql server instances. So you first need to consider the edition of sql server you want to use (linked above) and then need to consider what exactly you want to do with your rows. It would be unusual for a database to consist of a single table - so perhaps you have more work ahead of you then planned.

Answer (score 0):

Much bigger than that ([524,272 terabytes to be exact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)). The main question would be one of disk space, max file size, filegrowth options, etc. I work with databases well in excess of a terrabyte, so 25GB shouldn't nake SQL flinch (unless you're using Express edition, where I think the cap is a puny 1GB)